# EnumDropDownListFor with Enum string value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have an enum like :

```
public enum StateEnum
{
    Updated = 0,
    Pending = 1,
    Failed = 2
}
```

The helper function `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => Model.State, "States")` is rendering :

```
<select id="State" name="State">
     <option value="0">Updated</option>
     <option value="1">Pending</option>
     <option value="2">Failed</option>
</select>
```

My question is : how to have an enum string value in the `option` value attribute instead of the integer ? Like :

```
<select id="State" name="State">
     <option value="Updated">Updated</option>
     <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
     <option value="Failed">Failed</option>
</select>
```

(it would be more user-friendly in the next page Url)

I could rewrite the `Html.EnumDropDownListFor` function in a htmlhelper extensions, but there is no better solution ?

Comment: You could always use javascript to update the `value` attribute of each option, (or write your own extension method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Andy's anwser, i wrote a helper but not sure it's the best way to do that. If any body have a better solution

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListWithStringFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var selectListItem = Enum.GetNames(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TEnum))).Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Value = p, Text = p }).ToList();
    return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectListItem, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the values of the enum as strings by using `Enum.GetNames`. You would then pass this list into the model and the dropdown would be created using `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Test, new SelectList(Model.Values))`.

You can see this in the following fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ynK4ss

Comment: Thanks it's a solution but it can be very surly if we have several enum in model, i prefer to write a helper extension

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `SelectList` as Andy suggested or you can have a `StateString` property with a getter like this:

```
public StateEnum State { get; set; }

public string StateString 
{ 
    get { return State.ToString(); } 
}
```

or if `State` is the string property, then bind `StateEnum` in the `EnumDropDownListFor` and change model to:

```
public StateEnum StateEnum { get; set; }

public string State
{ 
    get { return StateEnum.ToString(); } 
}
```